# D-ITG command in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

This is my command on sending the D-ITG command from ubuntu to windows receiver.

*$ Itgsend -a fe80::d8da:36bb:db82:65ac -C 10000 -t 20000 -c 512 -x ubuntulog*

The code above is not working. do you guys know what is wrong with this code?

thanks for the help

Comment: Tell us whatever you have tried. Does it work when the receiver is the localhost? Does it work when the receiver is another Linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

D-ITG commands are

> ITGDec, ITGLog, ITGManager, ITGRecv, ITGSend

Answer (score 0):

the correct way is :  ITGSend 
not Itgsend as you wrote it